# My Score variables for my Python quiz in GUI stay at 0

Tags: python, tkinter

For a school project, I am making a Quiz in TKinter python. The problem comes in my scoring system, the way it is supposed to work is adding a score depending on the 6th index of my questions dictionary which is referenced towards score variables for each subject category. But the problem comes when actually adding the score to the sections. It does not successfully add the score, keeping it at 0.

I have tried making the score global as it is in a class but I don't know how to even start to fix this. I have also tried to define the dictionary index and number as a score in the function but It still stays at 0.
[This is what happens, I have used a print statement to check the status of the score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObGew.png)

How would I go about fixing this?

Here is my code: (Edited so it only has the stuff that doesn't work)

```
from tkinter import *
import random


# Variables
background_color = "gray13"
foreground_color = "floralwhite"
btn_color = "mediumseagreen"
names_list = [] 
asked = []



mechanics_score = 0 
nuclear_physics_score = 0
waves_score = 0

python_score = 0
heuristics_score = 0
algorithims_score = 0 

def randomiser(): 
  global qnum 

  qnum = random.randint(1,15)

  if qnum not in asked: 
    asked.append(qnum)
  elif qnum in asked: 
    randomiser()

randomiser()

# Questions and Answers 
# Physics
# Question number: Question, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 4, Correct Answer placement, Category 
phy_qanda = {
  1: ['What is Mechanics?', 'The mechanical components of a car', 'an area of physics concerned with the motion of objects','the interactions between particles','A school of physics which concerns itself with waves',2,mechanics_score,'Mechanics'],
  2: ['Who theorised the existence of electrons?','JJ Thompson','John Dalton','Ernest Rutherford','Issac Newton',1,nuclear_physics_score,'Nuclear Physics'],
  3: ['What are the two different optics in physics?','Light and Sound','Ray and Wave','Dynamic and Mono','Rays and Orbits',2,waves_score,'Waves'],
  4: ['What is Newtons first law?','For every action there is an equal and opposire reaction','The amount of acceleration of a body is proportional to the acting force','Gravity acts towards the centre','An object at rest will remain at rest',4,mechanics_score,'Mechanics'],
  5: ['What is the mass of an electron?','1','2','1/1836','1.1836',3,nuclear_physics_score,'Nuclear Physics'],
  6: ['An image is virtual when..','..The rays cross each other','..The rays seem to cross each other','..The image is above the mirror','..The image is in the mirror',2,waves_score,'Waves'],
  7: ['How do you calculate centripetal force?','a = V^2/r','F = ma','A = V/t','F = mv^2/r',4,mechanics_score,'Mechanics'],
  8: ['An alpha particle is..','High velocity, but light electrons','Energy from the electromagnetic spectrum','A heavy, slow and positively charged helium nucleus','An ionised particle',3,nuclear_physics_score,"Nuclear Physics"],
  9: ['What is the equation for magnification?','i/O = M','1/i + 1/0 = 1/f = 2/r[f=R/2]','A = V/t','C = 2r',1,waves_score, "Waves"],
  10: ['‘For every action there is an \n equal and opposite reaction’ describes...','Newton’s first law of motion','The Square Cube law','Newton’s fourth law of motion','Newton’s third law of motion',4,mechanics_score, "Mechanics"],
  11: ['What charge is a Beta particle?','Neutral','Positive','All','Negative',4,nuclear_physics_score,'Nuclear Physics'],
  12: ['Wave optics believes that..','..Light is made out of rays','..Light can be split up from rays into waves','..Light is made up of waves','..Light is formed by waves and rays',3,waves_score, "Waves"],
  13: ['What forces effected the projectile in it’s motion?','Only Gravity','Gravity and Horozontial force','Gravity and Light','Nothing, it is only directed by the force exerted',1,mechanics_score,'Mechanics'],
  14: ['What is half-life in physics?','Half life is a popular video game franchise','The time it takes for the number of undecayed nuclei to fall to half its original number','The time it takes for decayed nuclei to regenerate','The half point for an organisim',2,nuclear_physics_score,'Nuclear Physics'],
  15: ['What is refraction?','The angle when a ray hits a reflective surface','When a light ray goes from one medium to another','The act of light travelling through space in waves','Light creating an image off of a reflective surface',2,waves_score,'Waves']
}
# Computer Science
# Question number: Question, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 4, Correct Answer placement, Category 
cs_qanda = {
  1: ['What is python in computer science?','Python is a programming language','Python is a search engine','Python is a type of snake','Python is a famous car brand',1,python_score,'Python'],
  2: ['What does the heuristic, ‘Match with the real world’ deal with?','Make the user able to edit and change their answers','Use familiar icons and concepts found in the real world','Conventions in programming','Able to show the user the status of the system',2,heuristics_score,'Heuristics'],
  3: ['What is an algorithm?','A version of the windows operating system','A type of programming technique that is similar to a class','A finite ordered sequence of steps to solve a problem','The observation of sequences within a computer program',3,algorithims_score,'Algorithms'],
  4: ['What is the data type for this?: 1.4','Float','Integer','String','Boolean',1,python_score,'Python'],
  5: ['Who made the design heuristics?','Jakob Nielsen','Jacob Nielsen','John Nelson','Rolf Molich',1,heuristics_score,'Heuristics'],
  6: ['When can Algorithms be used?','Only in Python','Any time to design a solution to a problem','When finding an error','Only when repairing computers',2,algorithims_score,'Algorithms'],
  7: ['What does this sign mean in python?: !=','Approximately','If this happens do this','Equal to','Not equal to',4,python_score,'Python'],
  8: ['What is the 9th heuristic?','Aesthetic and Minimalist Design','Recognition Rather than recall','Algorithms and Databases','Diagnose and Recover from errors',4,heuristics_score,'Heuristics'],
  9: ['How do you measure algorithm efficiency \n in terms of run time and space?','F equations','Small R cubits','Big O Notation','Y5 Rankings',3,algorithims_score,'Algorithms'],
  10: ['What does an If statement do?','Checks if something is true then executes it','Compares 2 values and returns a true or false','While a statement is true, it will loop a indefinitely until it is not','A block of code that only runs if called.',1,python_score,'Python'],
  11: ['What does the Heuristic ‘Diagnose Recover and Errors’ deal with?','Allows access for more efficient processes','Gives the user the freedom to personalise their experience','After making an error, the user will be able to recover easily','Follow already existing conventions',3,heuristics_score,'Heuristics'],
  12: ['What is the worst case for a search and sort algorithm?','O(n)','O(n/2)','F - (QT)','Y5 - 6',1,algorithims_score,'Algorithms'],
  13: ['‘Address = []’ is an example of what in python?','Variable','Integer','Dictionary','List',4,python_score,'Python'],
  14: ['‘Clean, Uncluttered, Visible’ is an example of what heuristic?','Help and Documentation','Flexibility and Efficiency of use','Aesthetic and minimalist design','Consistency and standards',3,heuristics_score,'Heuristics'],
  15: ['What is the best case for a quick sort?','Y4^4','F + (n^6)','n*log(n)','O(f^log(6)',3,algorithims_score,'Algorithms']
}

chosen_quiz = phy_qanda


class Quiz: # Actual quiz 
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.quiz_frame = Frame(parent, bg=background_color, padx=100, pady=100)
    # Geometry and placement of the UI
    self.quiz_frame.grid()

    self.question_label = Label(self.quiz_frame, text=chosen_quiz[qnum][0], font=("Tw Cen MT", "17", "bold"), bg=background_color, fg=foreground_color)
    self.question_label.grid(row=1,padx=10,pady=30)

    self.var1 = IntVar()

    self.rb1 = Radiobutton(self.quiz_frame, text=chosen_quiz[qnum][1],font=("Tw Cen MT", "11", "bold"),bg=foreground_color, fg=background_color,value=1,padx=10,pady=10,variable=self.var1)
    self.rb1.grid(row=2,sticky=W)

    self.rb2 = Radiobutton(self.quiz_frame, text=chosen_quiz[qnum][2],font=("Tw Cen MT", "11", "bold"),bg=foreground_color, fg=background_color,value=2,padx=10,pady=10,variable=self.var1)
    self.rb2.grid(row=3,sticky=W)

    self.rb3 = Radiobutton(self.quiz_frame, text=chosen_quiz[qnum][3],font=("Tw Cen MT", "11", "bold"),bg=foreground_color, fg=background_color,value=3,padx=10,pady=10,variable=self.var1)
    self.rb3.grid(row=4,sticky=W)

    self.rb4 = Radiobutton(self.quiz_frame, text=chosen_quiz[qnum][4],font=("Tw Cen MT", "11", "bold"),bg=foreground_color, fg=background_color,value=4,padx=10,pady=10,variable=self.var1)
    self.rb4.grid(row=5,sticky=W)

    self.confirm_button = Button(self.quiz_frame, text='Confrim', font=("Tw Cen MT", "13", "bold"), bg=background_color, fg=foreground_color, command=self.quiz_progress)
    self.confirm_button.grid(row=6,sticky=E)

    self.error_label = Label(self.quiz_frame, text = '', font=("Tw Cen MT", "13", "bold"), bg=background_color, fg=foreground_color)
    self.error_label.grid(row=7)

  def questions_setup(self):
    randomiser()
    self.var1.set(0)
    self.question_label.config(text = chosen_quiz[qnum][0])
    self.rb1.config(text = chosen_quiz[qnum][1])
    self.rb2.config(text = chosen_quiz[qnum][2])
    self.rb3.config(text = chosen_quiz[qnum][3])
    self.rb4.config(text = chosen_quiz[qnum][4])
  
  def quiz_progress(self):
    global score 
    choice = self.var1.get()
    score = chosen_quiz[qnum][6]
    if len(asked)>14:
      if choice == chosen_quiz[qnum][5]:
        self.confirm_button.config(text='Confirm')
        score += 1
    
        for i in physics_categories:
          print(i)
        print('Finished')
      else:
        self.confirm_button.config(text='Confirm')
        for i in physics_categories:
          print(i)
        print('Finished')
    else:
      if choice == 0:
        self.error_label.config(text = 'Please select an answer before continuing')
        choice = self.var1.get()
      else:
        if choice == chosen_quiz[qnum][5]:
          print(score)
          score += 1
          print(chosen_quiz[qnum][7] + ':' + str(score))
          print('Correct')
          self.questions_setup()

        else:
          print(chosen_quiz[qnum][5])
          print('Wrong')
          self.questions_setup()



if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = Tk()
  root.title("NCEA Study buddy")
  quiz_instance = Quiz(root) #instantiation, making an instance of the class Quiz
  root.mainloop()#so the frame doesnt dissapear
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal working example to show your problem? We really don't want to debug that much code.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm new to stackoverflow, I could just edit it right?

Comment: Yes please edit the question and only include the important bit to make sure it is minimal and working.

Comment: That is a bit much to read through, please provide the specific section, that is responsible for your score-keeping. if you print out the score you want to add before and after the line where you add it, that might give you a hint where the problem lies. if you add 0 for example...

Comment: a suggestion for future projects like this: for a question bank it would be better to use a dictionary or create a class for those

Comment: You know that if you change one of the values inside `phy_qanda[...][6]` it doesn't effect the rest of them or your `score` variables

Comment: I have just edited the code for the specific section sorry about that,

Comment: if the variable `score` is only kept in the function it will reset every time that function is called so You should keep a reference outside that function, near other scores perhaps

Comment: The `score` variable was added to make sure that the dictionary placement was referenced insdide the function properly. So I should put it somewhere else?

Comment: Since you are using a class, you can initialize the scoring variables in `__init__`. For example, `self.score = 0`.
And then increment them where necessary: `self.score += 1`.